# Error Handling while running sqlplus from shell scripts

Tags: unix, sqlplus

I need to validate whether DB connection is success/failure.

This is my code

```
report=`sqlplus -S /nolog << EOF
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
connect <<username>>/<<Password>>@hostname:port
set linesize 1500
set trimspool on
set verify off
set termout off
set echo off
set feedback off
set heading on
set pagesize 0

spool extract.csv
<<My SQL Query>>
spool off;
exit;
EOF`
```

I have tried the below option based on the thread  [Managing error handling while running sqlplus from shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734131/managing-error-handling-while-running-sqlplus-from-shell-scripts) but its picking the first cell value rather than the connection status.

```
if [ $report != 0 ]
then
echo "Connection Issue"
echo "Error code $sql_return_code"
exit 0;`enter code here`
fi
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar but executed it a bit differently.

First, I have list.txt which contains the databases that I would like to test. I am using wallet connections but this could be edited to hold username/password.

list.txt:

```
DB01 INSTANCE1.SCHEMA1 
DB02 INSTANCE2.SCHEMA2  
DB03 INSTANCE3.SCHEMA3  
DB04 INSTANCE4.SCHEMA4
```

I have OK.sql which contains the query that I want to run on each database.

OK.sql:

```
select 'OK' from dual;
exit
```

Last, I user test.sh to read list.txt, attempt to connect and run OK.sql on each line, and record the result in (drumroll) result.txt.

test.sh:

```
. /etc/profile
rm result.txt
while read -r name wallet; do
    echo "BEGIN-"$name
    if (sqlplus -S /@$wallet @OK.sql < /dev/null | grep -e 'OK'); then
        echo $name "GOOD" >> result.txt
    else
        echo $name "BAD" >> result.txt
    fi
    echo "END-"$name
done < list.txt
```

After the run check your result.txt.

result.txt:

```
DB01 BAD
DB02 GOOD
DB03 GOOD
DB04 GOOD
```

I hope this helps.