# sqlplus not properly ended script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i have a plsql script, which is not properly terminated:

```
create or replace package mypackage 
  ... (no semicolon/forward slash at the end)
```

the script is executed with sqlplus (12.1) on windows powershell:

```
sqlplus user/pass@host @my_not_properly_ended_file.pks
```

i would expect sqlplus to terminate with exit code 1 and an error message, but instead it prompts for input.

how can i get an error message and exit code in this situation?

edit: solution should also work with dml statements that are not terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Use a shell script to properly log everything. Have a look at this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734131/managing-error-handling-while-running-sqlplus-from-shell-scripts

Comment: question is not about how to log the output, but about how to force sqlplus to terminate with an error message when running a script with missing semicolon or forward slash at the end

Comment: You might try adding set define off to the top of your script. You might have a & in your script and it thinks you have a variable that needs user input.

Comment: not getting stuck in the sqlplus session kind of works with set define off, but it does not return an error message

Comment: there is no error, but sqlplus can't proceed on your anon block or create or replace proc until you supply a /

Comment: otherwise you can tell sqlplus to bork out on errors using the whenever error exit clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shell redirection instead of `@`:

```
sqlplus user/pass@host < my_not_properly_ended_file.pks
```

This will also prevent it getting 'stuck' if the script doesn't end with an `exit` command.

However, it won't return an error code to the shell in either case. As far as SQL*Plus is concerned you put the incomplete statement into its buffer but never attempted to execute it (as there was no slash); and as it didn't run, it didn't error. So setting `whenever sqlerror` or whatever won't make any difference either.

Comment: Yup my comment on whenever sqlerror was for someone who wanted to exit on an actual error :)